# is there any Package Manager for C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, package-managers

In node.js we generally has a npm as a package manager to install and uninstall dependencies in our project. Is there any Package manager for C++?

Comment: ya that's right. I am closing it. Thank you @TonyDelroy for directing me to the right answer